# How can we make sure other <ListItem> components as collapsible when one <ListItem> component get expands under <List> react material ui component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In currently working application we are using `react material ui` components to design a web page. And in one situation we have been using `<List>` material ui component as suggested in https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/ with few changes as per the application requirement. The scenario would be as below

[image: All <ListItem> Components Of <List> Component Are Collapsible on page load]

And now when I click on `CountryOne` listiteam then all three listitem's getting expanded as below.

[image: all three listitem's getting expanded]

But it should not happen. Actual expectation is current clicked listitem only should get expanded and other two listitem's should be in collapsible state only.

I have tried something with index of map only while iterating list of objects but not been successful. Please have a look into my sample code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-oxmu9x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your example, the reason behind this is all three Countries are using the same open property. Try doing this and see if it works:

```
this.state = { open: {countryOne: false, countryTwo: false, countryThree: false}

handleCollapse = (val) => { this.setState(state => ({
      open: Object.assign({}, state.open, {[val]: !state.open[val]})
    }))}

    // countries' ListItem onClick


    onClick={() => handleCollapse('countryOne')}
    onClick={() => handleCollapse('countryTwo')}
    onClick={() => handleCollapse('countryThree')}
```

Comment: thank you for quick suggestion I have tried above but no luck. Please look here [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hnbxey](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hnbxey) whats happening with suggested changes

Comment: You also have to modify the in props of the Collapse UI Component:

Comment: <Collapse in={this.state.open['countryOne']} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit><Collapse in={this.state.open['countryTwo']} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit><Collapse in={this.state.open['countryThree']} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>

Comment: Excellent @Dom Garcia. Thank you so much for your time. Now Its working as expected. And I made <List> data as dynamic and modified `handleCollapse` function accordingly here [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hnbxey](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hnbxey). Thank you so much again @Dom Garcia. I am very happy to voted this answer.

Comment: can you please have a look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720935/how-can-we-customize-material-ui-expansionpanelsummary-expandicon-with-add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54720935/how-can-we-customize-material-ui-expansionpanelsummary-expandicon-with-add) ?