# How can we customize @material ui <ExpansionPanelSummary> expandIcon with Add & Remove Icons?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am very new to `ReactJS` and `@Material UI` & I tried different ways to workout but no luck yet. Can someone please guide me how I can override `ExpandLess` and `ExpandMore` icons with `Add` and `Remove` icons of  expandIcon. Here is code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d2xrnq. And I also notice @Material UI `<ExpansionPanel>` component using `defaultExpanded` attribute to expand all Expansion Panel's by default. So, is there any way to collapse all expanded Expansion Panel's with single click?

Thank you so much in advance for your time.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question. You want to replace `ExpandMore` with another icon, is that it? And there is no `ExpandLess` icon, it's just the `ExpandMore` icon that's been rotated with CSS. May I ask WHY you want to replace icons that make sense in an expand/collapse context with icons that are linked to creative/destructive actions? Finally, yes, you can control each panel's state through its `expanded` prop, so you could add logic to expand/collapse all panels with a single click.

Comment: I want to explain the reason behind my asking WHY. If I click on a `Remove` icon, I expect the panel to be removed entirely, not to collapse. And if I click on an `Add` icon, I expect the creation of a new panel (possibly after some form dialog). So using these icons to expand/collapse your panels would be very counter-intuitive (and quite contrary to Material 'philosophy').

Comment: @Jaxx, thanks for you time &  I completely agree with your opinion but my application UX team designed mocks in that way so after many tries for same & not seen any luck then I put same on here.Yeah I need to discuss same with UX team let see how it goes. And I hope you might notice here [https://react-d2xrnq.stackblitz.io](https://react-d2xrnq.stackblitz.io) even left hand side list items also having `Add` & `Remove` icons.  @Jaxx - If you have time, can you please share a sample code snippet how can make collapse Expansion Panel's with single click?

Comment: Actually, I was confused and thought you meant the `Create` and `Delete` icons (the pen & trashcan). Plus & minus aren't so bad, although they're not ideally suited either ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Using different icons is simply a case of importing them and using them in place of `ExpandMoreIcon`. In addition, we track every single panel's state (see point 2. below) and use a ternary to decide which icon to display depending on that state.

```js
  <ExpansionPanelSummary
    expandIcon={
      this.state.expanded[statIndex]
      ? <Remove onClick={this.handleToggleOne(statIndex)} />
      : <Add onClick={this.handleToggleOne(statIndex)} />
    }
  >
    // panel contents
  </ExpansionPanelSummary>
```

2. We keep track of individual panel states in the `expanded` array in state, and we also keep track off a 'grouped' toggle through `expandAll` boolean in state.
   `expandAll` is set to false by default, and the `expanded` array is initialized to all false values (as many as there are panels) when the panels are loaded.

Each collapsible panel's `expanded` prop is set to the corresponding `expanded` array value in state. This determines the state of the panel (collapsed if false, expanded if true).

We set up two handlers:
`handleToggleOne` is curried with the panel's index, and attached to the expand/collapse icon for that panel. It individually sets the state of the panel at the stated index.

```js
  handleToggleOne = (index) => () => {
    const { expanded } = this.state
    expanded[index] = !expanded[index]
    this.setState({ expanded })
  }
```

`handleToggleAll` is used to toggle all panels open or closed at once. We keep track and toggle the `expandAll` value in state, and set each element in the `expanded` array to that value. The handler is then attached to a global 'Toggle All' `Button`.

```js
  handleToggleAll = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ expandAll: !state.expandAll, expanded: state.expanded.map(e => !state.expandAll) }))
  }
```

You can find a working fork of your code here: https://react-wd5uxp.stackblitz.io

(code editor link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wd5uxp)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Jaxx. looks you shared final layout url of source code, can you please share actual source code url so I can go through the complete code & will try my end before confirm ?

Comment: @Venki Just did! :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Jaxx for your valuable time. I am very happy to vote & mark tick for your perfect answer and make me more sense your suggestions too. Your solution is perfectly working-out my problem. As I just started learning ReactJs and Material UI I may need your inputs in future too :). I hope you can help me. Thank you again Jaxx.